# javascript function into variable

Tags: javascript

Happy Holidays to all.
I'm trying to execute a function that I have saved in a variable, as I could do this?

I tried this.

```
funcVar = 'function (a, b) {c = a + b; alert (c);}';

document.write (funcVar);
```

but has no functionality, I want to use that function that is in the variable at some point.

Comment: Write?! You *could* `eval`, but... what's the actual usecase? In other words, why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: `eval` is your friend, it works for all things, just do `eval(funcVar)` and you're golden.

Comment: `eval` is not your friend. `eval` is slow, hard to debug, and causes more problems than it solves. It solves almost no problems that can't be solved better with another technique.

Comment: `eval` is your friend that drinks all your beer and vomits on your couch. With friends like those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Write it as a function, not a string
- Call it, not write it to the document as if it were a string of HTML
- Pass arguments as it doesn't make sense to add `undefined` to itself

You should:

- Not use globals

Such:

```
var funcVar;
funcVar = function (a, b) {
    var c = a + b; 
    alert (c);
};
funVar(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a function, that's a string. You need to remove the quotes. And you need to execute it, not print it:

```js
var funcVar = function (a, b) {c = a + b; alert (c);};

funcVar(23, 42);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works. Thank you all.

```
var funcVar;
funcVar = 'function stop() {alert ("Test");}';
eval(funcVar);

stop();
```

Comment: If you are happy with all the potential problems of `eval` you may prefer the `new Function(body_string)` syntax